# Add and Edit do at one button React

Tags: reactjs

I am beginner of react. I want to add and edit both operations at one button.

but it is not working. what i tried so far is the attached code along with the screenshot image.

I will able to add the records and able to view the records when i click the table row particular row record will be passing to form successfully. But I want edit and add the record of same button. i create the method save inside method I called save and edit functions

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad51t.jpg)

**this is the function i wrote the below**

**async function save(users)**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {useEffect, useState } from "react";

function EmployeeLoad()
{
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
  const [mobile, setMobile] = useState("");
  var currentEmployeeID = "";

const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>
{
  Load();
},[])


  async function editEmployee(users)
  {
   setName(users.name);
   setAddress(users.address);
   setMobile(users.mobile); 
   currentEmployeeID = users.id;
   console.log(users.id);

  }


  async function  Load()
  {
     const result = await axios.get(
         "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employees");
         setUsers(result.data);
         console.log(result.data);
  }
 


  

async function save(users)
    {
     
    
     if(users.id == '')
    
     {
      await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/save",
      {
          name: name,
          address: address,
          mobile: mobile
      }
      );
      alert("Employee Registation success");
       
     }
     else
     {
      alert("edit");
     }
    }

  return (
    <div>
       <h1>Employee Details</h1>
       <div class="container mt-4" >
          <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>employeeName</label>
                <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeName"
                value={name}
                onChange={(event) =>
                  {
                    setName(event.target.value);      
                  }}
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>employeeAddress</label>
                <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeAddress" 
                 value={address}
                  onChange={(event) =>
                    {
                      setAddress(event.target.value);      
                    }}
                />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Mobile</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeMobile" 
                  value={mobile}
                onChange={(event) =>
                  {
                    setMobile(event.target.value);      
                  }}
                />
              </div>

              <button   class="btn btn-primary mt-4"  onClick={save}>Register</button>
            </form>
          </div>





      
<table class="table table-dark" align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Employee Id</th>
      <th scope="col">Employee Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Employee Address</th>
      <th scope="col">Employee Mobile</th>
      
      <th scope="col">Option</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
       {users.map(function fn(item)
       {
            return(
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <th scope="row">{item.id} </th>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td>{item.address}</td>
                <td>{item.mobile}</td> 
              
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"  onClick={() => editEmployee(item)} >Edit</button>    
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" >Delete </button>
                </td>


                </tr>
            </tbody>
            );
            })}
            </table>
                </div>
            );
        }
 
export default EmployeeLoad;
```

Comment: Please format the code

Answer (score 0):

Inside your table use the `currentEmployeeID` and render a save button if you are in edit mode

```
{currentEmployeeID === item.id ? (
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onClick={save} >Save</button> : (
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onClick={() => editEmployee(item)} >Edit</button> 
)}
```

So if this specific row is in edit mode, by pressing the button, it will save the entry, or else it will show "Edit". Dont forget to reset the `currentEmployeeID` when the save process completes.

Comment: {currentEmployeeID === item.id ? (
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"  onClick={() => editEmployee(item)} >Edit</button>)}    
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" >Delete </button>
                </td>

Comment: i wrote like this way but error displayed